# String Formatting using python

Tags: python, string, format

Is there any way to do this kind of string formatting using **PYTHON3**

```
*************Food*************
initial deposit        1000.00
groceries               -10.15
restaurant and more foo -15.89
Transfer to Clothing    -50.00
```

where the numbers are aligned to the right and the texts are aligned to the left

```
ledger = [

    {'amount':10000,'description': 'initial deposit'},
    {'amount':-10.15,'description': 'groceries'},
    {'amount':-15.89,'description': 'restaurant and more food costings'},
    {'amount':-50,'description': 'Transfer to Clothing'}
    
]
```

*please note that the value of the description key might depending on the user...
so It might be much longer or it might also not these ones*

if I do

```
string = ''
for dic in ledger:
    string += '{description:<23}{amount:>7.2f}'.format(**dic)
    string += '\n'

print(string)
```

the output is like this...

```
initial deposit        10000.00
groceries               -10.15
restaurant and more food costings -15.89
Transfer to Clothing    -50.00
```

**but I want the description part to stop before the numbers**

*also the decimal points are not aligning*

so what else am I missing here
Thank You!!!!

Comment: Perhaps f-string helps.

Comment: yes it is! could add your python code of your data?

Comment: All the Python formatting methods allow you to specify whether a field is left or right aligned. Read the documentation.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using f-strings you can do a lot of cool formating things in python 3. This [guide](http://cis.bentley.edu/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/Documentation-on-f-strings.pdf) is pretty good for learning about the different ways you can use f-strings in python.

To do a aligned table you can use fields like:

```
ages = {"Mike":10, "Leonardo":32, "Donatello":144, "Raphael":5}

for k, v in ages.items():
    print(f"{k:10}\t{v:10}")
```

Which will output

```
Mike            10        
Leonardo        32        
Donatello       144
Raphael         5
```

The `f` at the start of the string means its a f-string. The `:10` after the variable means that it will be aligned in a ten character wide field. By default strings and most objects are left aligned while numbers are right aligned. To change the alignement you can use the `<` or `>` option before the number e.g. `:<10`. You could automatically determine the field width or cut off strings that are too long easily.

Comment: If i do this

`ages = {"Mike":10, "Leonardo":32, "Donatello the Donny":144, "Raphael":5} # in the place of Donatello using _DONATELLO THE DONNY_

for k, v in ages.items():
    print(f"{k:10}\t{v:7.2f}")
`
The alignment doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to cut of the rest of the strings

Comment: For example, you could slice the string. If you change the print statement to `print(f"{k[:10]:10}\t{v:10}")` it will cut off the string.

Comment: Or if you wanted it to automatically determine the length with a set max length:```MAX_WIDTH = 20
width = max(a for a in ages.values())
if width > MAX_WIDTH:
    width = MAX_WIDTH

for k, v in ages.items():
    print(f"{k[:width]:{width}}\t{v:10}")```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by first calculating the with of the columns and then using f-strings. Also for the header of the table, `str.center()` is useful. Try:

```py
ledger = [{'amount': 10000, 'description': 'initial deposit'},
          {'amount': -10.15, 'description': 'groceries'},
          {'amount': -15.89, 'description': 'restaurant and more food costings'},
          {'amount': -50, 'description': 'Transfer to Clothing'}]

width_desc = max(len(d['description']) for d in ledger)
width_amnt = max(len(f"{d['amount']:.2f}") for d in ledger)

print('Food'.center(width_desc + 1 + width_amnt, '*'))
for d in ledger:
    print(f"{d['description']:{width_desc}} {d['amount']:>{width_amnt}.2f}")

# *******************Food*******************
# initial deposit                   10000.00
# groceries                           -10.15
# restaurant and more food costings   -15.89
# Transfer to Clothing                -50.00
```